# AKS CrashLoopBackOff for an image working without problem in docker host: logs: error: container containerd://x is not valid for pod flask-app

Tags: docker, apache, kubernetes, flask, azure-aks

I have a Flask app that should run on Apache2 server. I dockerized the app and it is working as expected on docker host in my test VM.

Once deployed on AKS the POD is stuck in state **CrashLoopBackOff**.
I am using a gitlab agent to deploy into AKS with gitlab-ci, the image is stored in gitlab private registry and the image was successifully pulled into AKS.

Here are the files/logs of my apps/AKS pod

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && python3 -m pip install flask \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./requirements.txt /var/www/webApp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /var/www/webApp/requirements.txt

COPY ./webApp.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/webApp.conf
COPY ./ /var/www/webApp/

RUN  a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN  a2ensite webApp.conf


RUN ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/error.log

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /var/www/webApp

CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: flask-app
  name: flask-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662 
        name: flask-appache
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        #securityContext:
            #privileged: false
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        #resources:
            #limits:
                #memory: 100Mi
                #cpu: 300m
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: gitlab
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**kubectl get pods**

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (2m27s ago)   8m18s
```

**kubectl describe pods flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx**

```
Name:             flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-agentpool-16891536-vmss000000/10.224.0.5
Start Time:       Tue, 02 Jan 2024 20:20:49 +0000
Labels:           app=flask-app
                  pod-template-hash=6d74447889
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 966c590b4ce639fa829feba8e597d63395af53ea231ab005f8d547e1721f8233
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.244.1.17/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.244.1.17/32
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.1.17
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.17
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/flask-app-6d74447889
Containers:
  flask-appache:
    Container ID:   containerd://5cdc5e1294267fce47bda95cb81bd09654a78fcf21dfe4bbaece786d195ea778
    Image:          registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662
    Image ID:       registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache@sha256:e798e4036dc13d72ef36c866d678fe295e3eac4b0058cd076330654bc56af317
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 02 Jan 2024 20:22:20 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 02 Jan 2024 20:22:20 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-sj7s8 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-sj7s8:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m57s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx to aks-agentpool-16891536-vmss000000
  Normal   Pulled     2m57s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662" in 864.830288ms (864.838488ms including waiting)
  Normal   Pulled     2m55s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662" in 827.635558ms (827.908837ms including waiting)
  Normal   Pulled     2m38s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662" in 875.237209ms (875.244689ms including waiting)
  Normal   Created    2m10s (x4 over 2m57s)  kubelet            Created container flask-appache
  Normal   Started    2m10s (x4 over 2m56s)  kubelet            Started container flask-appache
  Normal   Pulled     2m10s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662" in 827.338313ms (827.349353ms including waiting)
  Warning  BackOff    100s (x7 over 2m55s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container flask-appache in pod flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx_default(1177ffe3-61ff-418f-a37d-3b6d857c603b)
  Normal   Pulling    88s (x5 over 2m57s)    kubelet            Pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662"
  Normal   Pulled     87s                    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull/flask-appache:0a654662" in 862.977469ms (862.990149ms including waiting)
```

**kubectl logs flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx -c containerd://5cdc5e1294267fce47bda95cb81bd09654a78fcf21dfe4bbaece786d195ea778**

```
error: container containerd://c4c557b4e6f92ac803c7e9c42624e59e39941e3d731015e12c4bea193dd5db3b is not valid for pod flask-app-6d74447889-bghtx
```

**Logs in diagnostics settings in Azure**

```
exec /usr/local/bin/python: exec format error
```

**app.py **

```
from website import create_app


app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Can anyone help with that please ?

I tried making changes into the Dockerfile (changing the port exposed from 80 to 8080) but nothing happened. I searched from the log container not valid for pod and did not find anything related to that.

**EDIT**

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
- build
- deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_SOURCE_IMAGE: flask-appache:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  DOCKER_TARGET_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_TAG/$DOCKER_SOURCE_IMAGE
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2 
  CI_REGISTRY_TAG: registry.gitlab.com/sast6353642/sast-01-pull 
  CI_REGISTRY: registry.gitlab.com

pull-push:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:  
    - docker login ${CI_REGISTRY} -u ${USERNAME_REGISTRY} -p ${TOKEN_REGISTRY}    

  script: 
    - docker build . -t ${DOCKER_SOURCE_IMAGE}
    - docker tag ${DOCKER_SOURCE_IMAGE} ${DOCKER_TARGET_IMAGE}
  
    - docker push ${DOCKER_TARGET_IMAGE}
    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}   

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: 
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - kubectl config use-context k8s-flask/k8s-connection:k8s-agent-connection  
    - kubectl get pods
    - kubectl apply -f .
```

Comment: What command are you using to deploy your pod?

Comment: kubectl logs suggests an issue with the container ID, which might be due to a misconfiguration in the deployment.

Comment: I am using 'kubectl apply -f .' to deploy from a gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I uploaded the deployment in the post, see any misconfigurations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The cpu architecture of node pools (ubuntu) in AKS is ARM, I had to specify FROM **--platform=linux/arm** in my Dockerfile so the base image would be based on ARM instead on AMD64 so it can work in an ARM based host.

Exemple:
**FROM --platform=linux/arm python:3.10-alpine**

If the image is built in an Amd64 based host with the **--platform=linux/arm** prefix for base image in the Dockerfile this will not work => **Qemu has to be installed** so it can provide other system architecture platforms.

**Before installing Qemu**

```
debian@debian11:~/simple-flask$ docker buildx ls 

NAME/NODE DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  BUILDKIT                              PLATFORMS default * docker   default default         running v0.11.7-0.20230525183624-798ad6b0ce9f linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
```

**Installing Qemu on Debian/Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install -y qemu qemu-user-static
```

**You can see ARM now in platforms**

```
debian@debian11:~/simple-flask$ docker buildx ls


NAME/NODE DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  BUILDKIT                              PLATFORMS
default * docker
  default default         running v0.11.7-0.20230525183624-798ad6b0ce9f linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

If you build the image using CI/CD as gitlab-ci you just need to specify the **--platform=linux/arm** in you Dockerfile Before the image name.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

In order to run your dockized flask application on AKS, you can refer to below example.

Here I will be using a simple flask app that says *This is a Hello World application* using the below code. You can replace it with your own.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>This is a Hello World application</p>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Then containerize the app using docker. In this case, Flask application only requires the `flask` framework to run. Therefore, in the working directory, I will create a new file named ‘Dockerfile’ and use the following code:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "/app/app.py"]
```

and then build it using `docker build -t bravinwasike/flask-kubernetes .`

Output:
[image]

After creating the Docker image, ensure you push the Docker image into your Azure container repository using the following commands:

```
az login
az acr login --name <youracrname>
docker tag <the_name_you_want_to_show_in_ACR> <youracrname>.azurecr.io/<the_image_name_which_you_built>

docker push <youracrname>.azurecr.io/<the_name_you_want_to_show_in_ACR>
```

[image]

next we will deploy the containerized Flask application to the created AKS cluster
[image]

Create a deployment yaml file that refers to the image that I just pushed in my acr
[image]

Deployment and service yaml file combined

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: bravinwasike/flask-kubernetes:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app-deployment
  ports:
  - port: 6000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

then apply the yaml

```
 kubectl apply -f <whatever_you_have_named_your_file>.yaml
```

[image]

Done.. Now when you do `kubectl get pods` your pods are up
[image]

Your flask app is up

[image]

Comment: Hi, I did exactly the same steps than you with the exact files configuration for app.py, using the same Dockerfile and acr and also the same deployment and svc file but I am getting the same errors.

Comment: Would that be a problem with my AKS cluster ? I am using the same exact version than you 1.27.7

Comment: I am getting also a log in diagnostics settings logs: 'exec /usr/local/bin/python: exec format error'